# Include pre-encoded protocol buffer message within outer message

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to create a protocol buffer message in C++ that contains a pre-encoded inner message, without parsing and then re-serializing the inner message?

To clarify, consider the following message definitions:

```
message Inner {
    required int i = 1;
    // ... more fields ...
}

message Outer {
    repeated Inner inners = 1;
    // ... more fields ...
}
```

Suppose you have a collection of 10 byte arrays, each of which contains an encoded version of an Inner. You'd like to create an Outer that contains the 10 Inners. You don't want to hand-encode because Outer has other fields and may itself be included in other messages. Is there a way to get protocol buffers to directly copy the pre-encoded Inner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no a clean way, but there are a few hacky ways.  One is to define a second message like this:

```
message RawOuter {
    repeated bytes inners = 1;
    // ... same fields as Outer ...
}
```

`RawOuter` is identical to `Outer` except that the `inners` repeated field has been changed from type `Inner` to type `bytes`.  If you populate `inners` with the encoded instances of `Inner`, then serialize the `RawOuter`, you get exactly the same result as if you had built an `Outer` with the parsed verisons.  That is to say, the wire format for a nested message is identical to the wire format for a `bytes` field containing the serialization of that nested message.  This is one of those funny exploitable quirks of the protobuf encoding.

This hack has some problems, though.  In particular, it doesn't work well if you're trying to build an `Outer` instance that is embedded in some other proto, since you probably don't want to maintain two copies of every containing message, one using `Outer` and one using `RawOuter`.

Another, even hackier option is to inject the encoded messages into the `Outer` instance's `UnknownFieldSet`.

```
Outer outer;
for (auto& inner: inners) {
  outer.mutable_unknown_fields()
      ->AddLengthDelimited(1, inner);
}
```

The `UnknownFieldSet` is intended to store fields seen while parsing that do not match any known field number defined in the `.proto` file.  The idea is that this allows you to write a proxy server that simply receives messages and forwards them to another server without having to re-compile the proxy every time you add a new field to the protocol.  Here, we're abusing it by sticking a value into it that actually corresponds to a *known* field, but the implementation will not notice, and so it will write out these fields just fine.

The main problem with this approach is that if anyone else inspects your `Outer` instance in the meantime, it will appear to them as if the `inners` list is empty, since the values are actually hidden somewhere else.  This is a pretty ugly hack that will probably come back to haunt you later.  I would only recommend it if you have measured the performance difference and found it to be large.

Also note that the serialization code always writes unknown fields last, whereas known fields are written in order by field number.  Parsers are supposed to accept any order, but occasionally you'll find someone who is using the unparsed data as a hash map key or something and that totally breaks if the fields are re-ordered.

By the way, you can improve performance of both of these approaches by swapping the strings into place rather than copying, i.e.

```
raw_outer->add_inners()->swap(inner);
```

or

```
outer->mutable_unknown_fields()->AddLengthDelimited(1)->swap(inner);
```